# Gem::LoadError: can't activate jruby-openssl-0.9.5-java, already activated jruby-openssl-0.9.7-java

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, jruby-openssl

I am getting below error while doing *bundle install --path vendor/cache*:

```
Gem::LoadError: can't activate jruby-openssl-0.9.5-java, already activated jruby-openssl-0.9.7-java
```

I am using jruby 1.7.16. 
I tried deleting vendor, deleting Gemfile.lock but nothing is fixing this issue.

Can someone please suggest what can fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyway, solved it myself.
So, I had to uninstall the jruby-openssl 0.9.7 version and this is command I used:

    <i>gem uninstall -i /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@global jruby-openssl</i>

But I am still not sure why did it get installed at first. I am specifying 0.9.5 version in the cookbook.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling 0.9.7 version.

```
gem uninstall -i /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@global jruby-openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a default gem ... they behave slightly differently than normal ones

esp. when using `gem install/uninstall`

a `bundle exec` or `jruby -G -S ...` would have likely worked around this

Answer (score 0):

This is a conflict with the default gem installed with Mac OSX, bundle install fails with `Gem::LoadError: can't activate jruby-openssl-0.9.7-java, already activated jruby-openssl-0.9.5-java`. All you need to do is update your system gem by running:

`gem install jruby-openssl`

Comment: I tried installing but it did not work. I ended up uninstalling 0.9.7 version.
    gem uninstall -i /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@global jruby-openssl